# Sort array by range 10 by 10

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, range

Do you think i can optimize this piece of PHP code?
This code sorting a array by range because the script will turn on in a loop of 30000 iteration.

**IN**

```
Array
(
[0] => 39.89
[1] => 49.62
[2] => 59
[3] => 70.9
[4] => 82
[5] => 109.2
[6] => 120
[7] => 138
)
```

**LOOP**

```
    $newArr = [];
    foreach ($formField['surface_m2'] as $key => $surface) {
        if (substr($surface, -1) < 5){
            $value = floor($surface  / 10) *10;
        } else{
            $value = ceil($surface  / 10) *10;
            $value -= 10;
        }

        if(!empty($newArr[$value])){
            $newArr[$value][] = $surface;
        }else{
            $newArr[$value] = [];
            $newArr[$value][] = $surface;
        }
    }
```

**OUT**

```
Array(
[30] => Array( [0] => 39.89 )
[40] => Array( [0] => 49.62 )
[50] => Array( [0] => 59 )
[70] => Array( [0] => 70.9 )
[80] => Array( [0] => 82 )
[100] => Array( [0] => 109.2 )
[120] => Array( [0] => 120 )
[130] => Array( [0] => 138 )
)
```

Comment: Are you experiencing any issues with this code? Generally, SO is not used for optimization suggestions.

Comment: Also, we definitely need more information here. For instance, where is "$formField['surface_m2']" defined?

Comment: And what is the sorting logic?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the code in your `foreach` loop with `$newArr[floor($surface  / 10) *10][] = $surface;`

Comment: Yes $formField['surface_m2'] is defined.
I wanted to know if it is optimizable because I will launch it in production

Comment: This script __does not sort__ anything.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I second the motion

Comment: Should `10` be the last value of the first group or the first value of the second group? https://3v4l.org/EJJ3G

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
foreach ($formField['surface_m2'] as $number) {
    $newArr[$number - $number % 10][] = $number;
}
```

Subtracting `$number % 10` from the number will result in the number truncated to the tens place.

`ksort($newArr);` to sort the groups by keys if you need it to be sorted.

And to sort the groups:

```
foreach ($newArr as &$group) {
    sort($group);
}
```

It may be more efficient to just `sort()` the entire array before grouping it, though. I'm not sure.

---

Actually, I was curious so I did some testing, and sorting before grouping seems to be faster for smaller arrays (count < 300), but slower for larger arrays. It's not a big difference, though (≈10%).

Comment: You probably want the `[]` as this will overwrite when there are multiple elements in the same segment.

Comment: Thank you so much. I complicated the task while the solution is so simple.

Comment: You could also cheat and sort the input before the `foreach()` - they will then all be added in order.

Comment: @NigelRen Oh yeah, I actually added that to the end of the answer a couple of minutes ago, (although I could probably be more explicit about what I meant). I'm not sure which way would run faster, but that definitely would be simpler code, which I always prefer unless it makes a big difference

Answer (score 5):

```
$newArr = [];
foreach($in as $surface) {
    $key = (int) ($surface/10)*10;
    $newArr[$key] []= $surface;
}
```

By casting to int the value is rounded down. It is then added to the corresponding post in $newArr. Done this way PHP "assumes" it should start out with an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

I will prefer `array_reduce()` for this task, Let's do it like-

```
<?php
$array = array(39.89,49.62,59,70.9,82,109.2,120,138);
$results = array_reduce($array, function ($result, $n) {
    $result[floor($n / 10) * 10] = [$n];
    return $result;
}, array());

print_r($results);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/e5kgH

Comment: Compare with the result array in the question

Comment: @splash58 ohh, my bad, I just missunderstood :( thanks.

Comment: @splash58 sir **Edited**, and used `array_reduce()`